# How to make a request with the body of url form encoded structure?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, fetch

I have a post request where i need to send x-www-form-urlencoded keyValue pair parameters and content-type should be x-www-form-urlencoded.Here,I am sending Json as a body.I just wanna know how to send this in body and call it in cart function

> url: http://something/carts/{cart_id}
>
> postman form body = {id}: {value}

```
   static post(url, headers, body, resolve, reject) {
   fetch(`${this.data}${url}`, {
   headers: headers,
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify(body)
 })
      .then((resp) => {
        resolve(resp.json());
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err))
    }

   static Cart(id, product_id) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   this.post(`/carts/${cart_id}${product_id}`, {
  //Does this url correct.

   "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   "X-Authorization": this.authorization_key
        }, resolve, reject)
    })
 }
```

Comment: Your `body` shouldn't be JSON, it should be value pairs, e.g. `body: key=value&key2=value2`

Comment: @LGSon yeah you are right.But how do I send it?.see that's the body:id=prod_31q0o3JBgwDdjR&quantity=5 and how do I recieive it  in url  form format.

Comment: @LGSon I have a product id as body? I dont know how to send it dynamically.

Comment: Check the dupe link, it show how to collect data.

Comment: @LGSon url search param does not work in react native.

Comment: I don't know React, just knew it couldn't be JSON, hence my comment and not an answer.

Comment: @LGSon well,then how do I recieve data coming from from the server in form url format....!???

Comment: Well, if your existing question doesn't ask that, post a new that does.